# include yajsw in maven build

Tags: maven, yajsw

My project uses YAJSW wrapper. When i build project, i simple copy jars, required by YAJSW into assembly. So YAJSW's jars simple commited into my svn. I don't like this because my project hold 25 MB of space and 20 MB of that is YAJSW's libs.

I want to try:

- delete unnecessary YAJSW's libs, but i don't know which of them are required.
- download required libs from repo during build. But how to make it easy without listing all YAJSW jars in dependencies?

It will be best if there is a YAJSW pom with dependencies, but i don't find that. Maybe someone create that, so i can upload it to my repo?

Answer (score 2):

This is most fundamental things you need to copy in your `assembly` cycle:

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>
        your_yajsw_folder
    </directory>
    <outputDirectory>/yajsw</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>bat/</include>
        <include>conf/</include>
        <include>lib/</include>
        <include>scripts/</include>
        <include>wrapper.jar</include>
        <include>wrapperApp.jar</include>
    </includes>
</fileSet>
```

Right now I'm trying to add the `wrapper.jar` and `wrapperApp.jar` from maven, hence removing it from the assymbly file. However for that I might need to edit the scripts to look for the jar in the `lib` folder instead of the `wrapper_home`

I found the maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.rzo.yajsw</groupId>
    <artifactId>wrapper</artifactId>
    <version>11.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.rzo.yajsw</groupId>
    <artifactId>wrapperApp</artifactId>
    <version>11.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I have done this - please check out my project at:

https://github.com/griels/yajsw-maven-mk2

I think there are some other projects that have performed such an integration, e.g.

https://github.com/neo4j-attic/yajsw

But I couldn't find much info on them.

Alternatively, if you can find some way to run the YAJSW Gradle build scripts from Maven, you might be able to use that. I had to track down most of the dependencies by hand.

Comment: Hi, I cant access the provided link to your project "mk2" is it taken down? thx in advance

Comment: Hi, @KapaA, I'm afraid I don't have the time to maintain this so I've taken it down (I did mention it to the authors years ago). Hopefully you can find some automated way of integrating the official YAJSW. Thanks!

Comment: hi TerrestrialIntelligence, ah that's ok thanks for the response